# change high chart value depending on response of server

Tags: ajax, json, apache, highcharts

hai this is my html code

```
 <select id="difques">
            <option value="firstfivemonth">firstfivemonth</option>
            <option value="nextfivemonth">nextfivemonth</option>
        </select>
```

this my code for calling server by using ajax in jquery........

```
 $('#difques').change(function(){
                     $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "ManyQuestionGraph",
                                data: "graphfor="+$('#difques :selected').val()+"&value="+${value},
                                success: function(data){
                                    var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                                    options.series[0].color='red';
                                    options.xAxis.categories=obj.value;
                                    options.series[0].data=obj.month;
                                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                                }  
                            });
                        });
```

my highchart code is

```
               var chart;
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                       var options  = {
                            chart: {
                                renderTo: 'graphreport',
                                type: 'column'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Rating'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may']
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                min: 0,
                                max: 5,
                                title: {
                                    text: ''
                                }
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function() {
                                    return ''+
                                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
                                }
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Rating',
                                data: [1,2,3,4,5],
                                color: '#77c4d3'
                            }]
                        }
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

and my servlet code is

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonobject.put("value",[5,4,3,2,1]);
                    jsonobject.put("month",['jun','jul','aug','sep','oct']);
                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().write(jsonobject.toString()); 
}
```

and my web page will look like this.....
[image]

but when i select next five month in the select combo box it calls the server by using ajax and i can get the json data from server during success of ajax but when i pass the data to highchart it looks like this.......

[image]

am i doing it wrong or did i made some mistakes in coding......

help me...........

Comment: Could you show example of your returned JSON? Also, make sure before creating new chart that previous one is destroyed.

Comment: {"rate":",3.5,0,0,0","month":"'jun','jul','aug','sep','oct'"} this is my returned json

Answer (score 0):

This bit looks wrong to me:

```
options.xAxis.categories=obj.value;
options.series[0].data=obj.month;
```

Isn't that round the wrong way ? The months are the categories and the value is the data ? Try:

```
options.xAxis.categories=obj.month;
options.series[0].data=obj.rate;
```

Comment: Updated answer now I've seen your jsom

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong for Highcharts, change from:

```
{
     "rate":",3.5,0,0,0",
     "month":"'jun','jul','aug','sep','oct'"
}
```

To something like this:

```
{
     "rate": [3.5,0,0,0],
     "month": ['jun','jul','aug','sep','oct']
}
```